# Simulate Temporal Table error in SQL Server to demonstrate fix

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, ef-core-3.1

I raised this question which has a potential good solution attached, but raising this as a new question

I have a table Invoice in the database which I am setting UpdatedDate to GetDate

If I deliberately run a method that updates this in parallel I can get the error I want to see

Data modification failed on system-versioned table 'table name' because transaction
time was earlier at than period start time for affected records.

```
static async Task UpdateInvoiceAsync()
{
    var connectionString = @"";
    await using var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var sql = "UPDATE Invoice SET UpdatedDate = GETDATE() WHERE ID = 'CF10E62E-07EB-4F7B-ACB3-95C0BDEC9884'"; 

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    cnn.Open();
    await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
}

static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var taskNo = 1; taskNo < 1000; taskNo++)
    {
        tasks.Add(UpdateInvoiceAsync());
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

My question is how to reproduce this within EF Core so that I can prove to my tester that the proposed fix below actually works?

```
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
sqlOptions =>
{
    sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationAssemblyName);
    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        new List<int>()
        {
            80131904
        });
        sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(240);
});
```

Its not possible to run queries in parallel via EF core so not sure how to simulate this?

Paul

Comment: I'm afraid the question isn't clear. When do you get this error in EF and what's the proposed fix? Where do you want to run the code that causes the error? Also, why is there a column `UpdatedDate` if the table is temporal? Or, if that's one of the required start/end dates, why update it?

Comment: UpdatedDate is my own column not a generated one I am getting this on purpose and then I need to prove that the retry logic which I am adding allows the operation to be retried without any issues

Comment: The error would happen in the SaveChangesAsync call in ef core